# Create multidimensional json from HashMap<String, String>

Tags: java, json, jackson, hashmap

I need to create a multidimensional `json` from a `hashmap` which i have to generate from a .csv file.
The `Hashmap` mapping from csv works fine.
If i convert the created `Hashmap` with a simple `ObjectMapper` i just get an single dimension `json` with all attributes of the `HastMap`.

Is it possible to check the `keys` of the `Hashmap` and if the key starts with "baseData" it gets in the subobject `baseData` like in the following `json`.

```
    {
    "testCaseData": {
        "baseData": {
            "verkaufsproduktart": "special",
            "tarifgeneration": "string",
            "ursprungAngebotsnummer": "string",
            "mandant": "string",
            "sparte": "string",
            "beratungsprotokollId": "string",
            "bonitaet": "string",
            "verkaufsname": "string",
            "aktionsnummer": "string",
            "erstellernummer": "string",
            "verkaufsprozessart": "string",
            "kanalrichtung": "string",
            "versandweg": "string",
            "vertriebskanal": "TELEFON",
            "quellsystem": "standard",
            "kundenberater": "String",
            "vsnrErgoDirekt": "string",
            "vsnrRisikotraeger": "string",
            "versicherungen": [],
            "leistungsvereinbarungen": [],
            "beitraege": [],
            "abbuchungstagImMonat": "TAG_1",
            "zahlweise": "EINMALZAHLUNG",
            "angebotsstatus": "string",
            "angebotsstatusaenderung": "date",
            "haustarif": true,
            "versicherungsBeginn": "2020-01-01",
            "rabattWert": "PROZENT_2"
        },
        "storeData": {
            "personDataStore": [{
                "adresse": {
                    "hausnummer": "string",
                    "land": "Deutschland",
                    "ort": "string",
                    "postleitzahl": "string",
                    "strasse": "string"
                }]
         }
}
```

The objectnames like `testCaseData` and `baseData` is fixed and known. the rest of the data inside `baseData` for example needs to be generic (thats why i use the `hashmap`).

thanks for helping

Edit:

current Mapper

```
    public void getHashmapFromCsv(InputStream csvFile) throws IOException {
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvFile));
     List<String> completeInputList = 
 br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
     String[] baseLineArray = completeInputList.get(0).split(";");
     for (String singleCase : completeInputList.subList(1, 
 completeInputList.size())) {
         String[] singleCaseArray = singleCase.split(";");
         for (int i = 0; i < baseLineArray.length; i++) {
             if (i > singleCaseArray.length-1 || 
 singleCaseArray[i].equals("")) {
                 map.put(baseLineArray[i], null);
                 } else {
                     map.put(baseLineArray[i], singleCaseArray[i]);
                 }
             }
           
         }
         System.out.println(map);
         ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
         Obj.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
         String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(map); 

      } 
    }


{baseData_kundenberaternummer=12346798, VP3 Kdnr=null, beratungsprotokollId=BERATUNGSVERZICHT, VP3 Nachname=null, VN Postleitzahl=90344, abbuchungstagImMonat=J, telemarketingnummer=123456789, VP4 Titel=null, baseData_aktionsnummer=1000, VP4 Hausnummer=null, mandant=1, VP3 Vorname=null, VP1 Vorname=null, VP4 baseData_Kdnr=null, VP3 Titel=null, VP1 Hausnummer=null, zahlweise=QUARTALSWEISE, VN Nachname=Mustermann, versandweg=EMAIL, VP3 Hausnummer=null, VP4 Ort=null, VP4 Anrede=null, VN Anrede=HERR, tuwid=null, VP2 Nachname=null, haustarif=N, VP2 Hausnummer=null, VP3 Strasse=null, VP2 Kdnr=null, iban=DE99999999, VP1 Nachname=null, VN Vorname=Max, VN baseData_Kdnr=null, VP2 Titel=null, vertriebskanal=TELEFON, VP2 Ort=null, VN Geburtsdatum=01.01.1980, VN Titel=null, VP1 Strasse=null, VP2 Strasse=null, VN Hausnummer=60, verkaufsproduktart=standart, quellsystem=system, VP3 Ort=null, rabattWert=0, VP4 Vorname=null, Testfallname=5, VP1 Anrede=null, VP2 Anrede=null, versicherungsBeginn=0, VN Strasse=street , VP2 Vorname=null, tarife=zzz, VP1 Kdnr=null, kundencm=J, verkaufsprozessart=DIREKTABSCHLUSS, VP1 Titel=null, gespraechspartner vorname=Hans, VP1 Postleitzahl=null, VP3 Anrede=null, kontoinhaber=Max Mustermann, userId=123456789, VN gleich VP=N, VN Ort=City, VP4 Strasse=null, gespraechspartner nachname=Meyer, versandmail=test@test.com, VP1 Ort=null, VP1 Geburtsdatum=null, VP2 Postleitzahl=null, VP4 Nachname=null, bankname=Bank, VP2 Geburtsdatum=null, VP3 Geburtsdatum=null, VP4 Postleitzahl=null, bic=NORSDE51XXX, VP3 Postleitzahl=null, VP4 Geburtsdatum=null}
```

Comment: Can you please add how your hashmap looks like?

Comment: Can you show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current solution so we see how the input looks like?

Comment: edited with the current mapper.

Comment: please add the map you've printed for better understanding

Comment: Added. you can see in the printed Map. that i named some of the fields baseData_*. These values need to go in a subobject called baseData like in the json above

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found a way to do it:

First of you need to setup two (or how many subobject you need) Hashmaps like so:

`HashMap<String, Object> testCaseData = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

The most inner Hashmap can be:

`HashMap<String, String> baseData = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Then you need to work your way from the inner Hashmap to the outer by filling up any needed fields.

`baseData.put("verkaufsproduktart", "SZSSZL");`
`baseData.put("tarifgeneration", null);`

Then the inner Hashmaps into the outer Hashmap

`testCaseData.put("baseData", baseData);`

Then all you need to do is create a Mapper instance

`ObjectWriter Obj = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).writer().withRootName("testCaseData"); String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(testCaseData); System.out.println(jsonStr)`

By default the root value is "Hashmap". If you want to rename it to your required name you need to add:

`.writer().withRootName("testCaseData");` like in the example above.

That will do it. Just in case someone is searching for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have constructed the hashmap properly, `objectMapper` would do the job.
There's no way it will give you the "One Dimensional" JSON if you've constructed the hashmap properly.

Check whether your hashmap is constructed properly, just like you've given the JSON result.

So from your added details, it seems that you've constructed the hashmap only for baseData. That's why you're getting an "One Dimensional" JSON.

Comment: Mhh i dont think i have an Error in my Hashmap. Right now i have a `Hashmap<String, String>` . Can i create a Hashmap like `Hashmap<String,Hashmap> ` and so on and still can parse it?

Comment: You can simply do a Hashmap<String,Object> and can incorporate and map all these.